# Prove that, in a triangle, $α = 2β \ \implies \ a^2 = b^2 + bc $

Tags: geometry, triangles

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to solve this task!

I have to prove that in a triangle ABC, if $α = 2β$, then $a^2 = b^2 + bc $

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you know about triangles that might be relevant here?

Comment: A couple of things: 1) As already hinted, try working this problem yourself and include your work in the question. 2) In triangle $ABC,$ the symbols $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ represent the vertices, so we understand that clearly. What do $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ represent? We can guess their meanings based on frequently-used conventions, but why make us guess? When you ask a question in which letters mean certain things, say explicitly what each letter means.

Comment: Well, if the triangle is a right triangle with sides 3, 4, and 5 and a,b c, $\beta$ are the numbers 1, -7, $\pi$, and $10^{100}$ respectively this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Sine rule:

$$\frac{a}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{b}{\sin \beta} \rightarrow \frac{a}{2\sin \beta \cos \beta}=\frac{b}{\sin \beta} \rightarrow a=2b\cos \beta$$

Cossine rule:

$$b^2=a^2+c^2-2\cdot a\cdot c\cdot\cos \beta \Rightarrow b^2=a^2+c^2-2\cdot a\cdot c \cdot\frac{a}{2b}$$

$$b^3=a^2b+bc^2-a^2c \Rightarrow b(b^2-c^2)=a^2(b-c)$$

$$(b-c)[a^2-b(b+c)]=0$$

So,

$b=c$ or $a^2=b^2+bc$

If $b=c$ then $a=b\sqrt{2}$ then we get a right triangle and still have the relation $a^2=b^2+bc$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A=2B$

$$
\sin(A-B)=\sin(B)
$$
$$
\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin B\sin C
$$
$$
\sin^2A-\sin^2B=\sin B\sin C
$$
Applying the sine rule we get

$ a^2-b^2=bc $

Comment: A quick mathjax/latex tip. If you are putting a sine or cosine in mathmode, place a "\" before it so that the words don't come out italicized. That is $\sin$ is with a slash, versus $sin$ without a slash.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.